# WP7: Get DeviceUniqueId from _connected_ phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can I somehow get the DeviceUniqueId from the phone currently connected to the PC? (from a .NET C# desktop-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question.

If it's possible to get that information, you're best bet is using the CoreCon10 APIs for WP7. The Device class has Device.ID and Device.Name properties which might have the data you're looking for.

For more information on WP7 and CoreCon10 integration, checkout my blog post @ http://justinangel.net/WindowsPhone7EmulatorAutomation

Basically, you'll have to get the connected WP7 device, and then check Device.ID and Device.Name. If that have the data you're looking for, it might be possible to install an app that'll report that back to you (on unlocked WP7 devices).